# DatabaseError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to setup a database for a django application.

So when i attempt to create database everything works fine except one thing. At the end, this message comes up:

> You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
>           Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):

If i type "yes" and hit the enter key then it gives me this error:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\Django>cd myapps

D:\xampp\htdocs\Django\myapps>python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superuse
rs defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 220,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351,
 in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
, line 109, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 190,
in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 172,
in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py
", line 70, in create_superuser
    call_command("createsuperuser", interactive=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
166, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 220,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\cr
eatesuperuser.py", line 72, in handle
    User.objects.get(username=default_username)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 132, in
 get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 344, in g
et
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 82, in __
len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 273, in i
terator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 68
0, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 73
5, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 34, in e
xecute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
234, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use
 a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str).
It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicod
e strings.

D:\xampp\htdocs\Django\myapps>
```

I believe it is supposed to prompt me to enter a username and password if i choose "yes" but it doesn't prompt me anyhting and give me this error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is due to a [bug in Django related to system usernames that contain non-8-bit characters](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15778).

As a workaround, you can say "no" when asked to create a superuser and use the [createsuperuser](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#createsuperuser) command to create a new superuser with a different name:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): no
Installing index for auth.Permission model
Installing index for auth.Group_permissions model
Installing index for auth.User_user_permissions model
Installing index for auth.User_groups model
Installing index for auth.Message model
No fixtures found.
$ python manage.py createsuperuser --username yourname
E-mail address: email@example.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
```

Comment: I figured out the problem. The problem is the Turkish character in my windows login name, Şenol. So what i did is, created a new user in windows without any Turkish character in it then login with that user account. And it works perfectly.

Comment: What role does a superuser play in django?  I clicked no, do I need to now create a superuser in order to use django?